# Can you predict the polynomial degree of the numerator and denominator of a rational functions first derivative

Tags: calculus, functions

I have graphed out rational functions of linear/linear, quadratic/quadratic, linear/quadratic, and quadratic/linear as well as their first derivatives using the quotient rule. I am just wondering provided I know the degree of the numerator and denominator polynomials of the rational function, can I find this out for the first derivative?

Answer (score 2):

If you have polynomials $p(x)$ of degree $n$ and $q(x)$ of degree $m$, let
$$
r(x) = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}.
$$
Then using the quotient rule
\begin{aligned}
r'(x) &= \frac{p'(x)}{q(x)}-\frac{p(x)q'(x)}{q(x)^2} \\
&= \frac{p'(x)q(x)-p(x)q'(x)}{q(x)^2}
\end{aligned}
As a start, and in general, the numerator has degree $n+m-1$ and the denominator has degree $2m$.  However, some terms in the numerator may cancel, so by exception the numerator could have a lower degree.  Moreover, terms in numerator and denominator may also have common factors, reducing the numerator and denominator's degrees.

I doubt that there is an easy rule to deal with all cases beyond saying the degree of the numerator is at most $n+m-1$ and that of the denominator is at most $2m$.

Comment: Thank you very much